# Azure Storage Table using Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I converted my .net MVC, Entity Framework and SQL server website into .Net with Storage Table as the cheapest database option in Azure.

I followed a repository pattern same as Entity Framework, Created Base Repository for common CRUD operation and other repositories as per table (entity).

This is my first implementation of StorageTable, I would like to get feedback and best practices so I can improve my code.

**BaseRepository**

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : TableEntity, new()
{
    private readonly CloudTable table;

    protected BaseRepository(CloudTableClient tableClient)
    {
        table = tableClient.GetTableReference(typeof(TEntity).Name);
        table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    public CloudTable Table
    {
        get
        {
            return this.table;
        }
    }

    public void AddEntity(TEntity entity)
    {
        TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(entity);
        table.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        /// Define a batch operation.
        TableBatchOperation batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            batchOperation.Insert(entity);
        }
        table.ExecuteBatchAsync(batchOperation).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    public TEntity Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Delete(entity);
        table.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        return entity;
    }

    public void Edit(TEntity entity)
    {
        TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(entity);
        table.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> FindBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        TableQuery<TEntity> tableQuery = new TableQuery<TEntity>();
        List<TEntity> list = new List<TEntity>();
        // Initialize the continuation token to null to start from the beginning of the table.
        TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;

        do
        {
            // Retrieve a segment (up to 1,000 entities).
            TableQuerySegment<TEntity> tableQueryResult =
                table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(tableQuery, continuationToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            // Assign the new continuation token to tell the service where to
            // continue on the next iteration (or null if it has reached the end).
            continuationToken = tableQueryResult.ContinuationToken;
            list.AddRange(tableQueryResult.Results);
            // Loop until a null continuation token is received, indicating the end of the table.
        } while (continuationToken != null);
        return list;
    }
}
```

**AccountRepository**

```
public class AccountRepository : BaseRepository<Account>, IAccountRepository
{
    public AccountRepository(AnimalHubContext context)
        : base(context.TableClient)
    {
    }

    public int GetNoOfOTPInLast1Hrs(string phoneNumber)
    {
        List<Account> list = new List<Account>();
        // Initialize the continuation token to null to start from the beginning of the table.
        TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
        var filter1 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PhoneNumber", QueryComparisons.Equal, phoneNumber);
        var filter2 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("CreatedDate", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1));
        var filters = TableQuery.CombineFilters(filter1, TableOperators.And, filter2);
        TableQuery<Account> query = new TableQuery<Account>().Where(filters)
            .Select(new List<string> { "PartitionKey", "RowKey", "Timestamp" });
        do
        {
            // Retrieve a segment (up to 1,000 entities).
            TableQuerySegment<Account> tableQueryResult =
                base.Table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, continuationToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            // Assign the new continuation token to tell the service where to
            // continue on the next iteration (or null if it has reached the end).
            continuationToken = tableQueryResult.ContinuationToken;
            list.AddRange(tableQueryResult.Results);
            // Loop until a null continuation token is received, indicating the end of the table.
        } while (continuationToken != null);
        return list.Count;
    }

    public bool ValidateOTP(string phoneNumber, int OTP)
    {
        List<Account> list = new List<Account>();
        // Initialize the continuation token to null to start from the beginning of the table.
        TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
        var filter1 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PhoneNumber", QueryComparisons.Equal, phoneNumber);
        var filter2 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForInt("OTP", QueryComparisons.Equal, OTP);
        var filters = TableQuery.CombineFilters(filter1, TableOperators.And, filter2);
        TableQuery<Account> query = new TableQuery<Account>().Where(filters);
        do
        {
            // Retrieve a segment (up to 1,000 entities).
            TableQuerySegment<Account> tableQueryResult =
                base.Table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, continuationToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            // Assign the new continuation token to tell the service where to
            // continue on the next iteration (or null if it has reached the end).
            continuationToken = tableQueryResult.ContinuationToken;
            list.AddRange(tableQueryResult.Results);
            // Loop until a null continuation token is received, indicating the end of the table.
        } while (continuationToken != null);

        Account phoneNumberOTP = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault();

        if (phoneNumberOTP != null && phoneNumberOTP.PhoneNumber.Equals(phoneNumber, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            && phoneNumberOTP.OTP == OTP)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Singleton TableContext**

```
public class AnimalHubContext
{
    private readonly CloudTableClient tableClient;

    public AnimalHubContext(IOptions<ApplicationConfigurations> applicationConfigurations)
    {
        var cloudStorageAccountName = applicationConfigurations.Value.CloudStorageAccountName;
        var cloudStorageKey = applicationConfigurations.Value.CloudStoragekey;
        // Retrieve storage account information from connection string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(cloudStorageAccountName, cloudStorageKey), true);

        // Create a table client for interacting with the table service
        this.tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
    }

    public CloudTableClient TableClient
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tableClient;
        }
    }
}
```

**Entity**

```
public class Account : BaseModel
{
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public int OTP { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseModel : TableEntity
{
    public BaseModel()
    {
        PartitionKey = "IN";
        RowKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you did not keep the async API?

Comment: I'm using existing non-async MVC controller and Service layer, I replaced Entity framework SQL layer with StorageTable.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest keeping the async API intact and also inject the table as it is the actual dependency, not the context. (Explicit Dependency Principle)

As this is meant to be used by derived classes, its members should be `virtual` to allow derived classes to `override` the default beahvior if needed

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IBaseRepository<TEntity> 
    where TEntity : TableEntity, new() {
    private readonly CloudTable table;

    protected BaseRepository(CloudTable table) {
        this.table = table;
        this.table.CreateIfNotExists(); //using synchronous API
    }

    public CloudTable Table {
        get {
            return this.table;
        }
    }

    public virtual Task AddEntity(TEntity entity) {
        TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(entity);
        return table.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation);
    }

    public virtual Task AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities) {
        /// Define a batch operation.
        TableBatchOperation batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();
        foreach (var entity in entities) {
            batchOperation.Insert(entity);
        }
        return table.ExecuteBatchAsync(batchOperation);
    }

    public virtual Task<TEntity> Delete(TEntity entity) {
        TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Delete(entity);
        return table.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation);
    }

    public virtual Task Edit(TEntity entity) {
        TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(entity);
        return table.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation);
    }

    public virtual Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> FindBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll() {
        TableQuery<TEntity> tableQuery = new TableQuery<TEntity>();
        List<TEntity> list = new List<TEntity>();
        // Initialize the continuation token to null to start from the beginning of the table.
        TableContinuationToken continuationToken = null;

        do {
            // Retrieve a segment (up to 1,000 entities).
            TableQuerySegment<TEntity> tableQueryResult =
                await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(tableQuery, continuationToken);

            // Assign the new continuation token to tell the service where to
            // continue on the next iteration (or null if it has reached the end).
            continuationToken = tableQueryResult.ContinuationToken;
            list.AddRange(tableQueryResult.Results);
            // Loop until a null continuation token is received, indicating the end of the table.
        } while (continuationToken != null);
        return list;
    }
}
```

The table reference would be the responsibilty of the derived class

```
public class AccountRepository : BaseRepository<Account>, IAccountRepository {
    public AccountRepository(AnimalHubContext context)
        : base(context.TableClient.GetTableReference(typeof(Account).Name))
    {
    }

    //...code removed for brevity
}
```

The asynchronous API should be maintained through out the class, other wise if a synchronous API exists, that should be used if not taking advantage of the async API

For example

```
public virtual void AddEntity(TEntity entity) {
    TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(entity);
    table.Execute(insertOperation);
}
```

Comment: Agreed with some of your suggestion. I Added my context class now, pls have a look.

Comment: I used Context class to create a single connection from database, and also keeping common TableClient code in context class.